# Draw a pixelated character or a sprite in TASM using loop?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

Is there a way to draw a pixelated character in TASM using loop? Like draw Mario using LOOP command.

Our professor asked us to do this, but I can't think of any way to do it. :/

So far, I've been using CX only to output colors for certain rows and columns numerous times. It's working alright, but I'm going against the instruction.

Comment: Using a LOOP instruction means having a counter in CX. That's it.

Comment: Our professor says that we must use LOOP command. I guess she doesn't know what she's talking about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.

What is a picture/image on a computer, typically? It's a 2d array of pixel colors.

How do you draw it on the screen?

Suppose, the image is 64 by 64 pixels.

So you can copy the pixel colors from the array to the screen one by one in 64 rows, each of which consists of 64 elements.

Can you see two nested loops here? Can you use the `LOOP` instruction for at least one of them? How about both?